# r - automatically add y axis in highchart

Tags: r, highcharts

I was using *highcharter* package in R. When I created a highchart object, it seemed that I had to add y axes in hc_yAxis function. For example

```
library(highcharter)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
data(edhec)
R = edhec[, 1:3]
height = 650
columns = ncol(R)
top = 1.1/2.9 * height/(2 + columns)
hc <- highchart(type = "stock")
hc <- hc_yAxis(hc, 
               list(height = height/(2 + columns)), 
               list(height = height/(2 + columns), top = top + height/(1 + columns)), 
               list(height = height/(2 + columns), top = top + 2*height/(1 + columns)))
for(i in 1:columns) {
  hc <- hc_add_series_xts(hc, R[, i], yAxis = i - 1)
}
hc <- hc_scrollbar(hc, enabled = TRUE) %>%
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_538())

hc
```

How can I automatically add y axes to my figure according to the number of columns in R?

Comment: Hi @eric-hung. Thanks for point this out. I'm working on a function to add automatically an arbitrary number of `yAxis`. I'll answer the question if I got sometihng simple ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now there's a function to create an  arbitrary number of `yAxis`. It's called `create_yaxis` (you'll need to download the development version):

```
library(highcharter)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

data(edhec)
R <- edhec[, 1:3]

hc <- highchart(type = "stock")
hc <- hc_yAxis_multiples(hc, create_yaxis(naxis = 3, heights = c(2,1,1)))

for(i in 1:ncol(R)) {
  hc <- hc_add_series_xts(hc, R[, i], yAxis = i - 1, name = names(R)[i])
}

hc <- hc_scrollbar(hc, enabled = TRUE) %>%
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_flat())

hc
```

You can see a example here: http://rpubs.com/jbkunst/create_yaxis

Comment: Hi @jbkunst, how can I set yaxis titles?Inserting  for instance `title=list(text=names(R))` as an argument in the `create_yaxis` function does not generate an error but does not show the text either.

Comment: By now is not possible, but is easy if you do the next: `axis <-  create_yaxis(naxis = 3, heights = c(2,1,1))` and `names <- c("A", "B", "C")` and merge them using (for example) `newaxis <- purrr::map2(axis, names, function(x, y){
  x$title <- list(text = y)
  x
})
` and then use  `hc_yAxis_multiples(newaxis)`

Comment: Hi @jbkunst. I attempted to execute your example in the comments above and I received Highcharts error 18 when I navigate to Google Dev Tools: The requested axis does not exist. This error happens when setting a series' xAxis or yAxis property to point to an axis that does not exist. Is this still a valid workaround? Thank you